# How many inclusion preserving maps of subsets?

Tags: co.combinatorics, puzzle

Let $S$ be a set with $n$ elements and $\Sigma_k= \{ R\subseteq S \mid |R|=k \}$. For $k\le n/2$ how many bijections $f$ are there between $\Sigma_k$ and $\Sigma_{n-k}$, such that $x\subseteq f(x)$?

For $k=1$ clearly the answer is the number of derangements of order $n$. I'm really mostly curious about the case $n=2k+1$, and even then I would just be happy with some estimate or euristic for the answer. Are there "many" such maps, or only a "few"? I have no intuition whatsoever for this.

The question has surely been asked before, at the very least [**here**](http://www.apprendre-en-ligne.net/crypto/magie/card.pdf), where a proof of Berlekamp is also given showing that the answer is not zero. (My original source for the card trick is actually the delightful [*Mathematical Puzzles: A Connoisseur's Collection*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812019) of Peter Winkler.)

Comment: This estimate is probably very far from the real answer, but in the corresponding bipartite $(\Sigma_k,\Sigma_{k+1})$-graph (I consider the case $n=2k+1$) all vertices have degree $k+1$, thus it contains at least $(k+1)!$ perfect matchings (this is a general fact.)

Comment: For $n=2k+1$ a lower bound is $\left(\frac{k^k}{(k+1)^{k-1}}\right)^n$. See http://homepages.cwi.nl/~lex/files/countpms2.pdf.

Comment: @RichardStanley: I don't completely follow - shouldn't the $n$ in the paper correspond to ${n}\choose{k}$, the size of $\Sigma_k$, here?

Comment: Both comments above are applicable to the general case, which can be regarded as a ${n-k}\choose{n-2k}$-regular bipartite graph with $2 {{n}\choose{k}}$ vertices. Thank you.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch: oops, you are right. This change just increases the lower bound.

Comment: @RichardStanley: hugely so. So now based on your formula, for $n=2k+1$, we can say that a lower bound is $>\big(\frac{k+1}{e}\big)^{{2k+1}\choose{k}}$ and obviously an upper bound is $\le (k+1)^{{2k+1}\choose{k}}$. (Notice that the ratio of logs of these bounds approaches 1 as $k$ grows, which makes them good enough to satisfy my original curiosity.) If you want to make this into an answer I'll gladly accept it.